# Potential Distribution in Container with 2 Electrodes?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions

Suppose I have two electrodes (modelled as point electrodes) inside a finite rectangular prism container, and I connect the electrodes to a DC power supply, such that one of the electrodes can be considered grounded at $0$ volts, while the other electrode is at $5$ volts. I then also impose the usual Neumann boundary conditions on each of the $6$ faces. The result is that I have to solve Poisson's equation in this container, with these two point electrode voltages fixed, as well as with those boundary conditions. How can I find the potential distribution everywhere inside this container?

Comment: Why do you impose von Neumann boundary conditions for your box container? If physically it's a conductor, Laplace boundary conditions are more appropriate. Also, if you assume the four electrodes to be exact points inside your box, you'll run into some difficulties as the problem is not well defined. You'll have to assume that they are little spheres, which amounts to more Laplace boundary conditions. If your box is infinite, you can solve it using method of images, if not, a numerical solver is necessary.

Comment: The Neumann boundary conditions I'm thinking of are the standard ones to model how an electric field behaves across an interface between two linear dielectrics with no free surface charges:
$$\varepsilon_1\vec{\nabla}\phi_1^{\perp}=\varepsilon_2\vec{\nabla}\phi_2^{\perp}$$$$\vec{\nabla}\phi_1^{||}=\vec{\nabla}\phi_2^{||}$$

Comment: So using point electrodes is not well-defined? Why not?

Comment: Just take the case of one electrode in vacuum. If it's a sphere you can fix it's potential at its boundary. As the radius shrinks to a point, keeping the same voltage at the sphere, the potential goes to zero everywhere. The shape of the electrode matters.